# Prove that if cancellative property applies then it's a group

Tags: group-theory

How to prove the following?

Let $x$, $y$, $z \in G$. If $x*y=z*y \Rightarrow x=z$, then $(G,*)$ is a group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't true. In $\mathbb{R}$, if $x-y=z-y$ then $x=z$. But $(\mathbb{R}, -)$ is not a group.

Comment: $(R,-)$ is not a group? Why?

Comment: Also, $(\mathbb R^+,+)$ is not a group, but $x+y=z+y\implies x=z.$

Comment: @gobaldia, consider $x,y,z\in \mathbb R$. Then it is clear that the associative property does not (in general) hold because $x-(y-z) = x - y + z \ne x-y-z = (x-y)-z.$

Comment: To the O.P.: $(\mathbb R,-)$ is not a group because "$-$" is not associative: $x-(y-1)=(x-y)+1\ne (x-y)-1.$  And as for my first comment, $+$ is asociative but $(\mathbb R^+,+)$  is not a group because it has no identity element...... Also $(\{0\}\cup \mathbb R^+,+)$ is associative and has an identity element but it is not a group because of a shortage of inverses.